# Updating Records with image field in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have an app where I want to add some fields with image. When I tried to add record its working fine but when I tried to edit the record,the edit form is not auto filling any data in it.. How can I write a function in view file which will do the purpose? My Model is

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
order = models.IntegerField()
image = models.FileField(upload_to='pics/',default='download.jpg') 

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('server_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

my update function in view file is :-

```
 from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
 from django.forms import ModelForm
import django.forms
from django import forms
from servers.models import Server
 def server_update(request, pk,        template_name='servers/server_form.html'):
  server = get_object_or_404(Server, pk=pk)
   form = ServerForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=server)
  if form.is_valid():
    ser = Server()
    ser.name = form.cleaned_data["name"]
    ser.ip = form.cleaned_data["ip"]
    ser.order = form.cleaned_data["order"]
    ser.image = form.cleaned_data["image"]
    ser.save()
    return redirect('server_list')
return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
```

Here 
form = ServerForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=server)
this line is I think causing problems, For normal forms without image
form = ServerForm(data=request.POST, instance=server)
this will work in populating data in edit file. But in this case of image record editing its not working..

My Template file is:

```
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: can you post your forms, have you used forms or Modelform ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update your edit view like this:- That line has to change like this-
 form = ServerForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,  instance=server)

```
def server_update(request, pk, template_name='servers/server_form.html'):
    server = get_object_or_404(Server, pk=pk)
    form = ServerForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,  instance=server)
    if form.is_valid():
        edit = form.save(commit=False)
        edit.save()
        return redirect('server_list')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending the data manually as a dictionary instead?

```
form = Form({'charfield': model.charfield, 'imagefield': model.image})
```

This way you could try some other options. Presumably you need to send the actual file data, so you would end up sending: model.image.read() instead of just model.image

Comment: its not working... Iam a newbie to Django.. Is that anyother way so we can save image with other datas? All documentation which I found is not explaining this..please someone help me..

Comment: I don't have a chance to try it right now, so I can't provide more useful information at the moment. I can try tomorrow though. I can think of somewhere in my project where I might use this.

Comment: is that a common requirement in everyones apps right? I dont find anything regarding this in any docs?